How to prove the diagonal matrix formula, $\mathbf{D=V^{-1}AV}$?
I've been stuck on proving the formula for $n\times n$ diagonal matrices,
$$\mathbf{D=V^{-1}AV}$$
which results from the diagonalization of $\mathbf A$ and where $\mathbf V=(\boldsymbol v_1\,...\,\boldsymbol v_n)$ is the matrix of its eigenvectors.
I wanted to prove that starting from
$$\mathbf A\cdot\boldsymbol v_\ell=k_\ell\boldsymbol v_\ell,\enspace \ell=\{1,..., n\}$$
We may use Einstein's notation to convert the above into
$$A_{j}^iv_i^\ell=k_\ell v_j^\ell$$
We can identify the LHS as $\mathbf{AV}$, but what about the RHS? Moreover the RHS shouldn't be misinterpreted as a sum over the index $\ell$.
I thought maybe using $\mathbf A=A_j^i\,\boldsymbol e_i\otimes\boldsymbol e_j$ and $\boldsymbol v_\ell=v_j^\ell\,\boldsymbol e_j$ could help solve this problem but I'm a novice in manipulating tensors.
Finally, it might be helpful to note that the RHS, $k_\ell v_j^\ell$, should turn out to be (somehow) $\mathbf{VD}$.

Your idea is correct, but you are probably not using the Einstein notation correctly. I guess you want to start from $\boldsymbol{AV}$, but for this case the formula in Einstein notation is
$$(\boldsymbol{AV})^i_j = A^i_\ell v^\ell_j,$$ where $v^\ell_j$ is the $\ell$-th component of the $j$-th eigenvector. Moreover, note that the upper index represents the row, while the lower index represents the column. Therefore, $A^i_\ell v^\ell_j=k_j v^i_j$ (note that in this equation we are not summing in $j$), and this is the Einstein notation for $\boldsymbol{VD}$, because
$$(\boldsymbol{VD})^i_j=v^i_\ell k_j\delta^\ell_j=k_j v^i_j,$$ where $$\delta^\ell_j= \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } \ell = j \\
0 & \text{if } \ell \neq j
\end{cases}$$ is the Kronecker's delta, useful for representing diagonal matrices in Einstein notation.

That's exactly what I was missing I somehow needed to use Kronecker's delta but didn't know how. Thank you!

$\ell$ repeats 3 times in the equation for ${\bf V}{\bf D}$.

@Julian To be consistent with the Einstein summation convention you should really have $k_j$ rather than $k_\ell$ so that you don't have the same index repeating 3 times

@BenGrossmann, TedBlack, thanks for pointing this out. I edited the answer accordingly.
